# Question about how do wordpress filters/actions work

Tags: filters, hooks

I have a question that I'm curious.

In WordPress we can add a filter or action like this code:

```
add_filter($filter_Name, $function_will_be_hook);
add_action($action_Name, $function_will_be_hook);
```

We can pass some parameters into **function_will_be_hook()**. But how does WordPress know that these parameters are related to its filters/actions.

Example:

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
    $content .= "I added some additon content";
    return $content;
} 

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

**How does WordPress know `$content` is the content of Post/Page (even when we change name of this param to some other name)?**

Comment: http://www.php.net/function.call-user-func

Answer (score 3):

For every filter or action hook that you use with the [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) or [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) functions, there is a corresponding [`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) or [`do_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) function called somewhere in the WordPress core.  This function sets up which parameters will be sent to the filter or action.

For the [filter hook `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) example that you gave, the filter hook is used in the [function `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) found in [`wp-includes\post-template.php` in WordPress 3.7.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L156):

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
    $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    echo $content;
}
```

In the `apply_filters` function call, the first parameter is the hook name, in this case `'the_content'`.  The next parameter, `$content`, is the value that we want to filter.  This will be the first parameter in your filter function (which is named `$content` in your `my_the_content_filter` function, but it could have any name).  Optionally, more parameters can be specified in the `apply_filters` function, and these will be passed in additional input parameters to the filter function.

For a filter hook, your filter function returns a filtered value, which in turn is returned by the `apply_filters` function.  For action hooks, there isn't any return value used.